How to make cookies notice load after everything else?
I'm trying to use two plugins in my website: CookieYes for a coockie notice and Shareaholic for floating share buttons.
The problem is the share buttons are overlapping CookieYes' popup, covering one of the buttons.
How can I change it so that the share buttons are rendered first and then the cookie frame is placed over it?

You'll have to adjust the CSS for those elements and change the z-index values.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can probably place a CSS z-index on the selector for the cookie notice. Since these are third-party plugins, check with the developer for support or use your inspector tools to identify what CSS class or ID to target that wraps the full cookie notice.

This solved it, thank you!
